# How to read excel file from a location with some preconditions?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

1. I need to read an excel where there are some folders and each folder contains many files in the location and my desired file will be in one of those folders. How I can read my desired file from that location? My file name is like `Daily Report on (18-Nov-2020)_ALL.xlsm` and I want to read as `df1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\(many folders here)\Daily Report on (18-Nov-2020)_ALL.xlsm',header = 1, usecols = "A:B,D:N,U,W,Z",skiprows = range(1,3))`.
2. The date part of my file name `18-Nov-2020` is not fixed and it is the current date of system. How can I change this date part in file name automatically everyday while run the program?

Looking forward to your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `glob` module. `'**'` means 'all possible directories and subdirectories' Also make sure, `recursive=True`

```py
from glob import glob
import os
today_file_path = glob(os.path.join(fixed_path, '**', today_filename), recursive=True)[0]
```

2. Use date formatting. `%d` is day of the month, `%b%` is shortened name of the Month, `%Y` is year

```py
from datetime import date
today_formatted = date.today().strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
today_filename = 'Daily Report on ({})_ALL.xlsm'.format(today_formatted)
print(today_filename)
```

output:

```
'Daily Report on (28-Nov-2020)_ALL.xlsm'
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark. My 2nd point is solved. Pls help me to resolve 1st point.  I don't know the specific folder location of my expected file. How I can read my desired file from many folders?

Comment: Is there a fixed set of folders, where the file could occur? So there are for example 3 different folders, but you don't know in which one to look?

Comment: No!! Folders are not fixed. Some path is fixed like C:\RPA\2020\(many folders those are not fixed)\Daily Report on (28-Nov-2020)_ALL.xlsm @Mark

Comment: I edited my answer to include the first question. Does it work for you?